# Используя функцию __toString как вывести эти properties?

Tags: php, классы, php7

Как вывести  названия продуктов, цены и имена владельцев через проход по итератору используя __tostring?

```
 <?php
  namespace lesson2;


  header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');


  class User{
    private $name;
    private $balance;

    function __construct($name,$balance){
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->balance = $balance;
    }

    public function getName(){
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function getBalance(){
        return $this->balance;
    }

    public function __toString(){
        return "У пользователя ".$this->getName()." сейчас на счету ".$this->getBalance()."<br/>";
    }

    public function giveMoney($user, $amount){
        if($amount > $this->balance){
            return 'Недостаточно средств!'."<br/>";
        }
        else{
            $this->balance -= $amount;
            $user->balance += $amount;
            return "Пользователь ".$this->name." перечислил ".$amount." пользователю ".$user->name."<br/>";
        }

    }

  }

  abstract class Product
  {
    private $name;
    private $price;
    private $owner;
    static private $products = array();

    function __construct($name, $price, $owner)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->price = $price;
        $this->owner = $owner;
    }

    public function setOwner(User $user)
    {
        $this->owner = $user;
    }

    public static function getProductIterator()
    {
        return new class (self::$products) implements \Iterator {
            private  $position = 0;
            private  $array;

            public function __construct($array)
            {
                $this->array = $array;
            }

            public function rewind()
            {
                $this->position = 0;
            }

            public function current()
            {
                return $this->array[$this->position];
            }

            public function key()
            {
                return $this->position;
            }

            public function next()
            {
                ++$this->position;
            }

            public function valid()
            {
                return isset($this->array[$this->position]);
            }
        };

    }

    public static function registerProduct($product)
    {
        if (in_array($product, self::$products, true)) {
            echo 'Введены одинаковые продукты ' . '</br>';
        } else {
            array_push(self::$products, $product);
        }
    }
  }

  class Processor extends Product{
    private $frequency;
    public function __construct($name, $price, $owner,$frequency)
    {
        parent::__construct($name, $price, $owner);
        $this->frequency=$frequency;
    }

  }

  class Ram extends Product{
    private $type;
    private $memory;
    public function __construct($name, $price, $owner, $type, $memory)
    {
        parent::__construct($name, $price, $owner);
        $this -> type = $type;
        $this -> memory = $memory;
    }
  }


    ///////////////////////////////////////////

    $a = new Processor("Intel",4500,"Kirill",3.9);
    Product::registerProduct($a);
    Product::getProductIterator();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала добавим в класс `Product` магический метод `__toString()` с помощью которого мы определим поведение класса при его конвертации в строку.

```
class Product
{
    private string $name;
    private string $owner;
    private int $price;
    /**
     * @var self[]|null
     */
    static public ?array $products = null;

    function __construct(string $name, string $owner, int $price)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->owner = $owner;
        $this->price = $price;
    }

    public static function makeIterator(): Iterator
    { 
        // Реализация
    }

    public function __toString(): string
    {
        return $this->name . ';' . $this->owner . ';' . $this->price . ';';
    }
}
```

Подготовим объекты и сохраним их в статическом свойстве.

```
$product1 = new Product('Процессор', 'Иван', 15860);
$product2 = new Product('Системный блок', 'Иван', 5860);
$product3 = new Product('Клавиатура', 'Иван', 1423);

Product::$products = [$product1, $product2, $product3];
```

Затем пройдёмся по итератору и конвертируем каждый объект `Product` в строку.

```
foreach (Product::makeIterator() as $product) {
    var_dump((string)$product);
}
```

Результат

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `echo` и так конвертирует выводимый объект в строку. Делать `(string)` - лишняя работа.

Answer (score 1):

Прежде всего следует расширить класс `Product` методом `__toString`:

```
public function __toString(){
    return "Продукт: " . $this->name .
           " цена: " . $this->price . 
           " владелец: " . $this->owner;
}
```

затем можно воспользоваться методом следующим образом:

```
$a = new Processor("Intel",4500,"Kirill",3.9);
Product::registerProduct($a);
$products = Product::getProductIterator();

foreach ($products as $p) {
    # неявный вызов метода __toString()
    echo $p;
}
```

Рабочий код находится здесь: [PHPize.online](https://phpize.online/?phpses=d5517d7721bdba45d4bd8099aeb0e2e5&sqlses=null&php_version=php7&sql_version=mysql57)

Comment: Зачем вызывать `__toString()` если он и так неявно вызовется при `echo $p;`?

Comment: Вам нужно так же определить ` __toString()` и для класса Processor, так как там есть новое свойство $frequency, У класса Product поля приватные так что нам нужно этот метод определить на основе метода  ` __toString()` самого Product. Отредактируйте ответ для полноты.

Comment: Вы правы @u_mulder. Исправил ответ.